# Change css background for my code

Tags: html, css, background

I'm not good in css, so please try to help me

I have this css code

```
#mo-stats-w1 {
    background: url("http://i48.tinypic.com/108dbix.png") 0px 0px repeat-x;
    /*height: 143px;*/
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #3EC4CD;
}
#mo-stats-w2 {
    padding: 12px 0px 0px 15px;
}

#mo-stats-w1 ul {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
    height: 59px;
}
#mo-stats-w1 ul li {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 1px;/*0px 0px 0px 0px;*/
    margin: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
    width: 174px;
    height: 59px;
    float: left;
}
ul#mo-stats-r1 li { background: url("http://i50.tinypic.com/23j0bcg.png") 0px 0px no-repeat; }
ul#mo-stats-r2 li { background: url("http://i50.tinypic.com/23j0bcg.png") 0px -59px no-repeat; }

#mo-stats-w1 ul li strong {
    font-size: 24px;
    height: 22px;
    font-family: Arial, "Nimbus Sans L", "FreeSans";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #1774C2;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px white;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 11px;
}


#mo-stats-w1 ul li span {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #3e3e3e;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 11px;
}
```

and this html code

```
    <div id="mo-stats-w1">

        <div id="mo-stats-w2">

            <ul id="mo-stats-r2">

                <li><strong>Status</strong></li>
                <li><strong>100</strong> <span>Points</span></li>
                <li><strong>30</strong> <span>Pending Points</span></li>
                <li><strong>0</strong> <span>Direct Referrals</span></li>

                <li><strong>Total</strong></li>
                    <li><strong>2</strong> <span>Links</span></li>
                    <li><strong>114</strong> <span>Views</span></li>
                    <li><strong>7</strong> <span>Unlocked Views</span></li>



            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
```

So the layout will be

[image]

Change the background for "Status" and "Total" to #4EC772 and background hover #7DD798 and the color for both words to be #FFFFFF

To be something like this

[image]

How i can do that please ?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WwY2v/

Thanks

Comment: add class to status and total `li`'s or use `li:nth-child(4n+1) {background: #4EC772;}`

Comment: Can you add some kind of identifier to the Status or Total LI fields? Such as class perhaps so then you can modify the class styling? Otherwise, will Status and Total always be that many list elements a part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `nth-child()` pseudo class to target those two `<li>` and do the same for the `color: #fff;` except specify the `<strong>` element after ..

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WwY2v/2/

This is what I added:

```
#mo-stats-r2 li:nth-child(4n + 1):hover {
   background: #4EC772;
}

#mo-stats-r2 li:nth-child(4n + 1) strong:hover {
   color: white;
}
```

Comment: You can include my comment as answer ;)

Comment: @Morpheus Perfect Dark thank you it's work :) is there another possible solution instead of nth-child..i can handle with it..but  i don't think my customer can do

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a class to the required elements like:

```
<li class='highlight'><strong>Status</strong></li>
...
...
<li class='highlight'><strong>Total</strong></li>
```

And use the following css:

```
.highlight {
   color:#FFFFFF; /* normal text color */
   background-color:#4EC772; /* normal bg color */
}
.highlight:hover, .highlight:focus {
   color:#FFFFFF; /* hover text color */
   background-color:#7DD798; /* hover bg color */
}
```